# Automate deployment of SSL private key using Ansible

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, ansible, private-key

I'm in the process of creating Ansible scripts to deploy my websites. Some of my sites use SSL for credit card transactions. I'm interested in automating the deployment of SSL as much as possible too. This means I would need to automate the distribution of the private key. In other words, the private key would have to exist in some format off the server (in revision control, for example).

How do I do this safely? Some ideas that I've come across:

1) Use a passphrase to protect the private key (http://red-badger.com/blog/2014/02/28/deploying-ssl-keys-securely-with-ansible/). This would require providing the passphrase during deployment.

2) Encrypt the private key file (aescrypt, openssl, pgp), similar to this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18951/secure-way-to-transfer-public-secret-key-to-second-computer

3) A third option would be to generate a new private key with each deployment and try to find a certificate provider who accommodates automatic certificate requests. This could be complicated and problematic if there are delays in the process.

Have I missed any? Is there a preferred solution or anyone else already doing this?

Comment: Totally and utterly insecure. Unless the private key is restricted to the host it belongs to, it cannot possibly serve its purpose. The key must be generated at the host it belongs to.

Comment: @EJP, I guessed I would get at least one comment like yours. I'm prepared to accept that this is less than desirable, but it still begs the question about how to do it. Is there some way to automate it?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to use [Ansible Vault](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_vault.html) to encrypt your private keys while at rest.  This would require you to [provide the vault password](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_vault.html#running-a-playbook-with-vault) either on the Ansible command line or from a text file or script that Ansible would read it from.

There really isn't a preferred method.  My guess is that if you asked 10 users of Ansible you'd get 10 different answers with regards to security. Since our company started using Ansible long before Ansible Vault was available we basically stored all sensitive files in local directories on servers that only our operations team has access to. At some point we might migrate to Ansible Vault since its integrated with Ansible, but we haven't gotten to that point yet.